# How should the accelerometer sample android app work?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I installed the [accelerometer sample app](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/index.html) from the android SDK 2.3 om the device (Nexus s). I get several balls falling towards one side of the screen and nothing changes their position.
Is there any place in which the expected behavior of this application is described?
Does anyone here knows the expected behavior?
I suspects it exposed a problem with the hardware operation.
Thanks,
Yoav

Answer (score 0):

Just ran it on a Nexus One... you hold the phone flat w.r.t. the ground. Tilting it slightly will cause the balls to fall towards the downmost edge of the screen, i.e. as if they were under the influence of real gravity.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't change nothing, just install another app that used the accelerometer and both applications started to work well...